# android NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled not working

Tags: android, notifications

How does `NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()` work?  I have tried to do the following `appPushEnabled = String.valueOf(NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled());`

however it is giving me an error?

Also it says it only works on some devices do I need a try catch on it?

Comment: Well, the docs and published source are lacking currently, but I'd imagine it's not `static`, if that's what you mean by "giving me an error". You'd need to call it on an instance, which you can get with the `static` `from(Context)` method. Beyond that, AFAIK, it'll return `true` unconditionally for any API<19, but should work as expected above that.

Comment: Post the error that it throws

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I dont get an error so much as I can't compile, it is just underlined in red

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After testing  for  few hours, here is what I have found.

In App Gradle file, com.android.support:support should be minimum 24 and compileSdkVersion has to be 24

```
android {    
    compileSdkVersion 24      
}    
dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
}
```

And then @petey 's answer will be working

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
boolean areNotificationsEnabled = notificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled();
```

Comment: I tried this in my MainActivity's onCreate method. But context is unresolved. Where can I get context?

Comment: @UniSoundWaterloo you can change it to "this" if you implemented method in Activity

Comment: @UniSoundWaterloo If, you're trying the method under a listener or some closed constructor, then change `this` to `YourActivity.this`

Answer (score 9):

Try using [NotificationManagerCompat.from(Context context)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationManagerCompat.html#from(android.content.Context)) method to get an instance of a NotificationManagerCompat object you may then be able to call `areNotificationsEnabled()` on.

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
boolean areNotificationsEnabled = notificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled();
String appPushEnabled = String.valueOf(areNotificationsEnabled);
```

Comment: I am still getting an error cannot resolve method areNotifcationsEnabled()

Comment: it doesnt compile, in android studio it is underlined in red and says cannot resolve method areNotificationsEnabled

Comment: Ahh..  please check your dependencies (what version of support you are using) and api targets.

Comment: V4 how do I check api targets?

Answer (score 1):

You should set your gradle with
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0"
**minimum.**

Comment: thanks, I am getting the following error

This support library should not use a different version (24) than the compileSdkVersion (23)

How do i edite the compileSdkVersion?

Answer (score -2):

[image: NotificationManager Api]

Looked up for the Api document, and I found that: the minimum api level should be 24.

Comment: use AndroidX so it will work with previous versions