# Is it safe to compile using Android 24?

Tags: android

I want to use `NotificationManagerCompat areNotificationsEnabled()`, and apparently from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016215/android-notificationmanagercompat-arenotificationsenabled-not-working/39486721#39486721) I can only use it if I compile my app using compileSdkVersion 24.

I couldn't find any Android 24 when I try to update my SDK from Android Studio; the only time my Android Studio will find Android 24 is if I just change my compileSdkVersion to 24 in gradle and sync.

So I'm pretty worried; is there any drawback of compiling using Android 24? Is it already stable?

Btw I've already added

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
```

in my gradl.e

Comment: If it weren't stable, it wouldn't have been released as a non-preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I  couldn't find any Android 24 when I try to update my SDK from Android Studio;

24 is an API level. It corresponds with Android 7.0.

> is there any drawback of compiling using Android 24?

No.

> Is it already stable?

It is neither "stable" nor "not stable". It is a JAR exposing a set of symbols that you can compile against, whether the real implementation of the classes, methods, etc. are provided by the framework JAR on the device or emulator.

> Btw I've already added `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'` in my gradle

I recommend raising that to the most current version, which IIRC at this moment is 24.2.1.